# Make user hold key for minimum amount of time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the user hold the spacebar for at least 0.3 seconds before the code triggers a function. I don't want this to disrupt any other code that could be happening in the background at that time. Anyone know how to do this?

I also want some text to turn green after 0.3s, so if you held the key for 1s, the text would be green after 0.3s of holding.

I have this base code:

```
document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        // Do Something, making sure spacebar is held for at least 0.3s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register the keydown with a timestamp and on keyup check the time elapsed.

Edit: If you want to trigger the function exactly after 0.3s you do it the other way around, on keydown you set a var noting space is down and set a `timeout` which checks if if the key is still down and then makes something green for instance.

Comment: So on onkeydown, I would start an interval, and then in the function above, i would check the interval is more than 0.3s? But what if I wanted some text to turn green after 0.3s, and continue being green until the key goes up?

Comment: In the onkeydown callback you could use setTimeout to call a function which checks to see if the space bar hasn't been lifted yet and if it hasn't, turn whatever text you want green.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. That makes sense